# Allow www-data to use another user - sudo or ssh

Tags: ssh, security, sudo, su, apache2

I would like to allow my PHP script (hosted with apache2) to execute commands with another user account.

I don't want another website hosted on the server to be able to connect to that another user account.

If i add a rule in /etc/sudoers then it will allow anyone of the website to use that user.

The solution i came was to use ssh, with a private key and public key. The PHP script launch a ssh connection with the server it is hosted on, on the desired user account.

Is there another way than my solution with ssh ?

Best regards

Comment: Do you want to execute just that one script with a different account or are you looking for actual permission separation so PHP runs every script in `/home/user1` as `user1` and `/home/user2` as `user2` (paths just to make it understandable)?

Comment: @Seth: look at the comment i wrote on the answer of pacey, it should answer you.

Answer (score 2):

My gut feeling tells me that what you're doing is a terrible idea. But actually you haven't given enough background on the reason why you'd want that and what the use case is to tell this really.

But your thought about `sudo` is wrong whether this is a good idea or not.

A sudoers entry is defined as:

```
  USER HOST = [(RUNAS)] [NOPASSWD:] [!] CMD[,...]
```

Which means that the user `USER` is being allowed to run `CMD` as user `RUNAS` (if given). So you could construct your `sudoers` entry like this:

```
  www-data YOUR-HOSTNAME = (YOUR-USER) NOPASSWD: /path/to/command
```

This will allow the user `www-data` on the host specified (or `ALL` if you give that as `YOUR-HOSTNAME`) to execute the program `/path/to/command` as user `YOUR-USER` without a password.

You can also supply `ALL` as command, allowing every command `YOUR-USER` has access to.

## Example

With your given exemplaric values a sudoers line would consist of the following (assuming `mydeployer` as the hostname and `thedeployer` as the username):

```
  www-data mydeployer = (thedeployer) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: I've writen a deployer: an API receiving calls from github/gitlab when I push with git, and when the CI tests have succeeded. I have a list of public/private keys which allows me to connect on remote servers, that are owned by a specific user, in order to avoid www-data to access them directly, else any other website hosted would have access to those private keys. What i want is to allow only the deployer to use the right user to execute the ssh call with the private key / public key.

Comment: if i understand, if I write `www-data https://mydeployer.myserver.com = (thedeployer) NOPASSWD ALL` it will only allow the deployer, or am i misunderstanding ?

Comment: another solution i have is to setup a password on my deployer-user, and disable ssh connection on it. Then i would do `echo $password | sudo -S -u myuser ...`. Don't know if it's still insane.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant you should give a `hostname` (see output of the command `hostname`) instead of an URL which won't work. I've added an example to my answer with your values given. Your other idea is far worse - since you would have to store the password somewhere which is a massive security problem (also sudo won't accept piped passwords).

Comment: it will accept with -S. I will test that today, thanks !

Comment: Oh, I didn't know. But as mentioned before this is generally a bad idea because it would force you to store the password somewhere in reach of the www-data user either in plaintext or in a form of encryption where www-data has access to the key to decrypt it which is a great security issue.

Comment: you are right, wasn't sure but now clearly a bad idea

Answer (score 0):

You can do dat using sudo and a specific sudoers configuration:

Execute the command from PHP as

```
sudo -H -u user2 /your/command parameters
```

Add to sudoers (`sudo visudo` command)

```
www-data    ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /your/command
```

This allows apache to run a specific command as another user

Comment: this allows any other website hosted on my server to execute the command as my user2. Not protected.